# Using asp C# issue with text-decoration:none;

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio-2010

I have this problem where my navigational links has an underline on hover. I tried to place text-decoration:none. I looked at my entire css but I can't find the cause for the underline.

So I used firebug and check the css of a specific spot where it gives me underline. I get this css which is not my own.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "EB Garamond";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local("EB Garamond"), local("EBGaramond"), url("http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/ebgaramond/v4/kYZt1bJ8UsGAPRGnkXPeFYbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff") format("woff");
}
```

My question is how do I change this style? and what is this style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to solve the problem is to use `text-decoration:none !important;` in a css selector, preferably a rather specific one.

That css is specifying a custom font to use, specifying where to log it from (http://themes.googleusercontent.com/) and what the default settings, such as font weight, should be when it used. Then any time the font-face is set to `EB Garamond` it will load those defaults. As that class is listed here it is not responsible for the underlining.

Answer (score 0):

it's probably anywhere else that overrides the style. Override it with:

```
a:hover{
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

the important tells the browser to override other stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

You also have to change the CSS to text-decoration:none on anchor tag (or its class or id) itself as well as the hover, active, and visited pseudo-classes if you don't ever want an underline on the link. Like this:

```
a, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Where you could use the selector like this for a class (where the class is applied to the a tag)

```
.class, .class:visited, .class:hover, .class:active
```

or like this for an id (where the a tag has this id)

```
#id, #id:visited, #id:hover, #id:active
```